# How can I add an external/third party library with type = 'module' using drupal_add_js()?

Tags: 7, javascript

```
  drupal_add_js('path_to_external_JS_file_on_CDN', [
    'every_page' => TRUE,
    'type' => 'external',
    'defer' => 'defer',
    'attributes' => [
      'async' => true,
      'type' => 'module'
    ],
  ]
);
```

I tried all combinations of the above, but I couldn't get it work. Is there a way to achieve it using `drupal_add_js()`, or should I use some other way?

I am trying to achieve this.

```html
<script type='module' src='path_to_external_JS_file_on_CDN'></script>
```

Edit: I added the code above in `my_module_preprocess_page(&$variables)`. The following code works as expected.

```php
drupal_add_js('path_to_external_JS_file_on_CDN', [
  'every_page' => TRUE,
  'type' => 'external'
]);
```

I just can't figure out how to load a JavaScript file with the `type='module'` attribute.

Comment: Have you tried with `type => file` as per the documentation here https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/javascript-api/adding-javascript-to-your-theme-or-module#s-with-drupal-add-js

Answer (score 0):

According the function's [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x) the `module` is not an allowed type, that's why it doesn't work.

You may try omitting the type or use the default one -  `file` instead.

The allowed types are 'file', 'inline', 'external' or 'setting'.

The hook you tried `my_module_preprocess_page(&$variables)` is a good choice.

You may also use the [hook_init](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_init/7.x) `YOUR_MODULE_NAME_init()` in a custom module to ensure your library is loaded everywhere. Please note that `hook_init()` is triggered after the theme and all modules are loaded already in the memory.

Please check if this solves your issue and put a note with the result.